# Android OnResume not called when using TabHost and LocalActivityManager

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

I set up a tabhost with two activities and since I could not use TabActivity I used LocalActivityManager, but when I switch tabs onResume is not called for the Activities within the tabs.  Here is my set up:

```
mlam = new LocalActivityManager(this, false);
mlam.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState);
tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
tabHost.setup(mlam);
```

I have the dispatchResume and dispatchPause placed in the proper places, but they only fire when the main tab activity gets an onResume or onPause.  I tried to solve my issue by firing the dispatchResume on bab change but that seems to not be firing.

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){

    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

    mlam.dispatchResume();

     }

});
```

Does anyone know how to make sure the onResume is fired for the activities so I can update the content within the tabs as they are selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize mlam with the second parameter true:
mlam = new LocalActivityManager(this, true);

And then only one activity is resume at the some time in the tabhost.