# Android: Shared preferences not saving the state of the buttons

Tags: android, button, save, android-tabhost, sharedpreferences

I have a tab-host with three activities and in each activity I have  buttons.

On each button press I am changing the background drawable resource

So now How can I save the pressed state of each button in all three child activities so that when I move from one activity to the other, the button pressed state will be reflected on moving back. first activity -> all 2 buttons pressed -> go to 2nd activity -> come back to first activity -> all buttons in first activity should be in pressed state with the drawable resource changed

I have two background Images.

button press -> highlited background image -> second time press same button  ->changes to normal background Image

For the first time when I run the application and If I press the button the background image is getting changed. If I go to 2nd child activity and coming back so the button is in pressed state with changed drawable resource. so Its fine

for the second time If I press the same button and coming back to the same activity from second activity. here its not working

First child activity -> press button ->high lighted background image changes ->go to second tabhost child activity -> come back to first child activity -> button is  showing the same background image after pressing(this is fine)

the problem is

now you press the same button in first child activity ->  background image changes to normal ->go to second tabhost child activity -> come back to first child activity -> but the button background resource is in highlighted instead of normal

and even If I run the application once again the button is showing the highligted background image

the below code I am using in my first child activity

EDITED

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(
            "sharedPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);

    int which = sharedPreferences.getInt("sharedPreferences", 1);
    switch (which)
    { 
        case 1:
            seatdirnbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon4); break; 
        case 2:
            seatdirnbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon4hlt); break;
        default:
            seatdirnbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon4); break;
    }
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
     boolean isclick = false;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(
            "sharedPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    if (isclick) {  
        seatdirnbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon4hlt);   

        editor.putInt("sharedPreferences", 2).commit();
    }
}
```

EDIT2

```
     public static boolean isclick = false;
private View.OnClickListener listner1 = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

    if (isclick) {
            seatdirnbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon4hlt);

        } else {
            seatdirnbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon4);
        }

        isclick = !isclick; 
    }

};
```

Comment: it looks like your `onPause` on has the condition for putting `int` 2 into SharedPrefs but never has the opportunity to put 1.

Comment: frankly im puzzled. you set up a boolean to always read `false` so that explains why one part of the condition isn't running. you'd have to make it correspond to when the button was clicked. Yet you're saying that the it's the *true* portion that is always running? Moreover, i think it is something better handled by simple boolean flags (maybe an array) to be toggled. and SharedPrefs for when the app is leaving.

Comment: Thanks, I got your point but as I am new to android  I am not getting any Idea how to implement this exactly.could you plz  elobarate it a little on how to handle this with flags.

Answer (score 0):

Try this change:

```
if (isclick) {  
        seatdirnbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon4hlt);   
        editor.clear();
        editor.putInt("sharedPreferences", 2).commit();
    }
else {
        seatdirnbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon4);   
        editor.clear();
        editor.putInt("sharedPreferences", 1).commit();
}
```

Comment: I am sorry I didnt undersatnd.

Comment: could you put a `log` statement in each if the `else` conditions?

Comment: @Alex, Not at all,I m sorry ,Thats not my intention.could u plz tell where do I need the break exactly? plz see my edit answer   boolean isclick = false; i have in onpause().

Comment: @mango, after putting the logs also, I'm not getting any data in logcat

Comment: for either condition of the if-else? restart the emulator, restart your ide, check again. look to see if both conditions are getting called. if so, try finding the id of the `btn` again right before setting the drawable.

Comment: @mango ,After debugging I came to know that the cursor is not going to else condition. else condition is not getting executed.

Comment: @mango, In onPause() I have given this condition  boolean isclick = false; please check my question once, I dont have any isclick method in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i meant:

```
boolean[] btnBool = new boolean[2]; // number of buttons

private View.OnClickListener listner1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        toggleBtn(0); //zero refers to which index of the array for button button
        setDrawables();
    }

};

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    toggleAllBtns();
    setDrawables();
}

private void toggleBtn(int index) {
    if(btnBool[index]) {
        btnBool[index] = false;
    } else {
        btnBool[index] = true;
    }
}

private void toggleAllBtns() {
    // first switch the values of the array
    for (int i = 0; i < btnBool.length; i++) {
        if(btnBool[i]) {
            btnBool[i] = false;
        } else {
            btnBool[i] = true;
        }
    }       
}

private void setDrawables() {
    // then set drawables based on values
    if (btnBool[0]) {
        seatdirnbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon4);
    } else {
        seatdirnbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon4hlt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. but sorry to say that when i click the button for the first time its getting the highlighted image and on resuming the tabhost child activity its reflecting as i want, but If I click on the same button once again it should show the normal image but its showing highlited once i  pause and resume the activity(I mean on going to second child activity and coming back to first child activity). should I have any different condition check for 2nd time click on the same button.

Comment: can i see what is happening in the listener? are you altering `btnBool` inside it? if everything is as it should, try findingbyid the same button once more before you set the background resource.

Comment: Plz check  EDIT2 in my question above. I am just changing the background image like that, I just kept your code inside the onResume() and even in the onclicklistner for the button seatdirnbtn.

Comment: OHHH sorry, Still its not working. the same thing is repeating here on button first click its getting highlighted background image but ongoing to second child activity and coming back to first child activity, its changing to normal backgrond image instead of highlighted, the button with highlighted background image i need on coming back to first child activity if i click on that. Thanks again

Comment: i gotta say i'm sorry. i'm testing it myself over here and things (after correcting a small error) seem to be working fine. hope you can get to the bottom of it.

Comment: YES, you r right but for me in tabhost this is not working. sorry for troubling you. Thanks